Software Updater issue - package dependencies cannot be resolved
I haven't installed any new software, only updates.  For about the past week I keep getting the message below when checking for updates using the Software Updater app on 24.04. It seems to be in a loop.
libgcc-s1:i386: Depends: gcc-14-base (= 14-20240412-0ubuntu1) but 14-20240412-0ubuntu1 is to be installed

Both libgcc-s1:i386 and gcc-14-base are both up to date according to the terminal.
Including the complete text from Software Updater:
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are   
missing or not installable.   
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are  
not allowed to be installed at the same time.    
    Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
     The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libgcc-s1:i386:   
      Depends: gcc-14-base (= 14-20240412-0ubuntu1) but 14-20240412-0ubuntu1 is to be installed


Please show us the complete output.

Here is the complete line from Software Updater:  This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgcc-s1:i386: Depends: gcc-14-base (= 14-20240412-0ubuntu1) but 14-20240412-0ubuntu1 is to be installed\

I didn't post any pictures of text.

Did you copy the message exactly or type it in yourself? Because the 2 package names are identical.

I copied and pasted the message.  I did not type it.  I found that odd also, it's also weird that package is already installed and up to date.

You  have a paired of matched conflicting dependencies which actually have identical versions. To solve this error upgrade and update the software (first upgrade, then update). Open the terminal and type:
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update 


Thank you.  I've tried that and it is still the same.
